# Unix and Signal Handlers (C)

Tags: c, unix, concurrency

I'm a student and I am trying to understand signals within a course about Unix programming.

To start, I wanted to test a simple example: a process makes a child and needs a confirmation of the actual creation.
I fork, and within the child I send a SIGUSR1 to the father with
kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
Then, within the father, I wrote a pause(); sys call to block the process until a signal is received, and then I wrote the 
(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) check.

Problem is, the signal is sent and the program stops, with no handler execution.

I compile it with

```
$gcc -Wall -o test test.c
```

I get no warnings, and the output is

```
$I am the father
$I am the child
$User defined signal 1
```

I know I could do this in other ways (with sleep sys call, etc.), but I just want to understand why this code doesn't work.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void new_child (int sig){
    write(1,"I made a new child\n",50);
}

int main(){
    pid_t child;
    struct sigaction sa;            
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sa.sa_handler = new_child;
    switch(child = fork()){
        case -1:
            printf("Error.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            printf("I am the child\n");
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
            break;
        default:
            printf("I am the father\n");
            pause();
            if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1){
                printf("Signal error.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("I'm done.");
            kill (child, SIGKILL);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

I know this question has already been asked, but I cannot seem to find a solution that works in my case.

Comment: You must change the signal at the beginning of the code so that it  can execute as soon as SIGUSR is received

Comment: Thank you very much. This actually worked! I found the sys call pause() to be very useful but my book didn't even have an example of its use.

Comment: `write(1,"I made a new child\n",50);` will write a lot of junk to file descriptor 1 as the length of `"I made a new child\n"` is much less than 50.  It's technically undefined behavior and can cause your program to fail.

Comment: @Anjaneyulu: "*You must change the signal at the beginning of the code ...*" this restriction is a bit tight. The signal handler needs to be install latest just before calling `fork()`.

Comment: @alk yest the signal handler not the signal

Answer (score 0):

You must change the signal at the beginning of the code so that it can execute as soon as SIGUSR is received – Anjaneyulu

"*You must change the signal at the beginning of the code ...*" this restriction is a bit tight. The signal handler needs to be install latest just before calling `fork()`.
                    – alk